# Geth unable to broadcast pending transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions

Been having issues since the last 2 or 3 days. Unable to get pendingTransactions mined despite Geth getting caught up to the latest block and having 25 connected peers.

The transactions were created from Mist and/or Ethereum Wallet. I can see them at `eth.pendingTransactions`, but can never get them to be mined.

Cleared pending tx by restart Geth, it would come back again after awhile, probably stuck in mempool somewhere, but never mined.

Anything I can do about it?

Comment: make sure geth is mining.

Comment: @niksmac I'm on Homestead. I can rely on other miners, right?

Comment: This seems to be related to the current situation: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/577iv5/cannot_send_any_transaction_tried_myetherwallet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have concluded that there was no issues with broadcast, but it was due to the spam attack at that time.

A quick way to check the txpool of the Ethereum network would be via `txpool.status`.

Comment: What do you mean by txpool.status? Is that a URL?

Comment: @emisilva `txpool.status` is a command you can run at the geth console (javascript syntax)